# Why are my buttons not working? (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner here trying to make a photo gallery by using back and next buttons to scroll through the photos. My buttons are not working and I have no idea why. Based on similar working code I have, they should be.

HTML:

```
<img src="TeamOrientation.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" id="gallery">

<button onclick="backward()">< Back</button>
<button onclick="forward()">Next ></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var imgs = [{src: "Team Orientation 2.jpg"},
        {src: "WorkEthic.jpg"},
        {src: "Enthusiasm.jpg"}
        {src: "Enthusiasm (2).jpg"},
        {src: "DoItRight.jpg"},
        {src: "DoItRight (2).jpg"}
        {src: "Dependability.jpg"},
        {src: "Dependability (2).jpg"},
        {src: "TeamOrientation.jpg"}]

var imgIndex = 0;


function forward() {
        if (imgIndex > imgs.length || imgIndex < 0) {
            imgIndex = 0;
            document.getElementById('gallery').src = imgs[imgIndex].src;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('gallery').src = imgs[imgIndex].src;
        }
        imgIndex++;

}

function backward() {
    imgIndex--;
   if (imgIndex > imgs.length || imgIndex < 0) {
            imgIndex = 0;
            document.getElementById('gallery').src = imgs[imgIndex].src;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('gallery').src = imgs[imgIndex].src;
    }
}
```

When I click the buttons, absolutely nothing happens. I have also tried doing this in the HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="< Back" id="back">
<input type="button" value="Next >" id="next">
```

and this in the JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

   document.getElementById('back').onclick = backward;

   document.getElementById('next').onclick = forward;
};
```

Nothing worked with it that way either. What do I need to change to get the buttons work? Based on everything I have tried, it appears to be a problem with the buttons just not calling the functions. I made sure that my HTML knows where to find the JavaScript already. It's not that.

Any solutions must use just JavaScript, no jQuery.

Here is a link to the actual website:

http://webpages.uncc.edu/dcarte50/Project/Products.html

Also, the working samples I have:

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = changeImage;
    document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = changeImage;
    document.getElementById('btn3').onclick = changeImage;
    document.getElementById('btn4').onclick = changeStyle;
};

function changeImage() {

        var imgs = [{src: "http://www.dogslovewagtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Dog-Pictures.jpg"},
                    {src: "http://splashanddashfordogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Dog-2.jpg"},
                    {src: "http://www.dealsinqueens.com/Dog-9.jpg"}]

        if (this.id == 'btn1') {
            var newImage = imgs[0].src;
        }else if (this.id == 'btn2') {
            var newImage = imgs[1].src;
        }else{
            var newImage = imgs[2].src;
        }

        document.getElementById('myImage').src = newImage;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KY4IzMcjX3Y/maxresdefault.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" name="myImage" id="myImage">
        </div>

        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="button" value="Image 1" id="btn1">
            <input type="button" value="Image 2" id="btn2">
            <input type="button" value="Image 3" id="btn3">
            <input type="button" value="Change Style" id="btn4">
        </div>
```

Comment: drop the parentheses from `onclick`.

Comment: Tried that, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your last *not working* example, you have values of `"Next >"`.  The HTML is assuming the `>` in there is the end of the tag.  Instead, use the character for `>` and `<`

List:

`< - '&lt;'`

`> - '&gt;'`

In your first *not working* example, maybe the problem is setting `onclick = "function();"`.

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work. Also tried just not including anything, as in the buttons just say "Back" and "Next". Still nothing.

Comment: Can you post the entire HTML page code?  Maybe try `<body onload = "function();"` in your `<body>` tag?  (Instead of using `window.onload();`"

Comment: Have you added any debug messages?  Try `console.log("yay");` on a button press to make sure it's not the code inside the method that is broken.

Comment: Just tried that (AngryCupcake's first suggestion), still not working. Not sure how to add the console.log thing?

Comment: So I think I get it. I put `console.log("yay");` as the first line in my methods, but when I click the buttons still nothing happens.

Comment: Try using the `<button onclick = "hi();">hi</button>` and then in the javascript, just have a test function: `function hi() { console.log('hi'); }`

Comment: See if that does anything...

EDIT: Also, does the `<body onload = "test();">` do anything?  That will tell you if your javascript [page] is loading.